# How can I prevent error CS0433 with MySqlConnector class in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm writing the index for a web application in .NET Core (V3.1), but when I'm programming the connection to the MySQL database that I'm using as the backend it comes up with this error:

```
Error CS0433: The type 'MySqlConnection' exists in both 'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' and 'MySqlConnector, Version=0.61.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d33d3e53aa5f8c92'
```

This error also comes up for MySqlCommand.

I can't seem to see where the assembly `MySqlConnector` is coming from as this is currently the code I'm using (which is at the top of my **.cshtml** file:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using MySql.Data.MySqlClient
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@{

ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";

string connStr = "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=csharptest;Uid=root;Pwd=*******;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

conn.Open();

string sql = "SELECT 5 RestaurantName, Add1, Add2, Town_City, Postcode, Rating FROM csharptest.Profiles";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

}
```

I've tried all sorts of solutions, including closing Visual Studio and removing both the **obj** and **bin** folders, then cleaning and rebuilding the solution but I can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: "I can't seem to see where the namespace MySqlConnector is coming from" - the error isn't talking about namespaces, it's talking about *assemblies. I don't know anything about MySqlConnector, but I *suspect* you should either have a dependency on the MySqlConnector package *or* on MySql.Data, but not on both.

Comment: Yes it is, my bad on that one. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: "I can't seem to see where the assembly MySqlConnector is coming from" - well presumbly you have a dependency on MySqlConnector. That wouldn't be present anywhere in your *code* - it's in your *project* file, which we can't see.

Comment: agreed, this is a reference problem - two assemblies are providing a type with an identical full name; the *best* option would be to decide which of those two you actually want, and remove the other one. It *is* possible to keep both using "extern alias", but that's an absurdly exotic feature that is very hard to use, and which is virtually never used in reality.

Comment: Thank you, this problem has been solved now, just working out the fallout elsewhere in the code where I hadn't quite realised the other assembly was being used.